# Way to differentiate ActiveRecord::Base.connection mysql joined query result?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My query:

```
records = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM leads WHERE leads.status=1 AND leads.account_id=1 AND leads.id > 253380")
```

Result:

```
    records.first
[253381, 1, "first", "king", "CEO", "Jewelry & Toys", "11111", "22222", nil, nil, nil, nil]

    records.fields
["id", "account_id", "first_name", "last_name", "job_title", "department", "work_number", "mobile_number", "address", "city", "state", "zipcode"]
```

So far all good, but now when I do left join in the query like below:

```
records = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM leads LEFT JOIN lead_details ON lead_details.id=leads.id AND lead_details.account_id = leads.account_id WHERE leads.status=1 AND leads.account_id=1 AND leads.id > 253380")
```

Result:

```
    records.first
[253381, 1, "first", "king", "CEO", "Jewelry & Toys", "11111", "22222", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]

    records.fields
["id", "account_id", "first_name", "last_name", "job_title", "department", "work_number", "mobile_number", "address", "city", "state", "zipcode", "id", "account_id", "stars", "score"]
```

**Note:** In the last array `"id", "account_id", "stars", "score"` are the columns of joined table

When I try to convert the records to hash The second `id`, `account_id` will overwrite the first `id`, `account_id` and the result will be like this

```
{"id"=>nil,
   "account_id"=>nil,
   "first_name"=>"first",
   "last_name"=>"king",
   "job_title"=>"CEO",
   "department"=>"Jewelry & Toys",
   "work_number"=>"11111",
   "mobile_number"=>"22222",
   "address"=>nil,
   "city"=>nil,
   "state"=>nil,
   "zipcode"=>nil,
   "stars"=>nil,
   "score"=>nil
  }
```

How to solve this overwriting of the data? Any way to partition the query result to nested array based on table name or something?

Comment: I think that the overwriting happens because of `#to_hashugar`. Can you show how the `llead` looks like before calling `#to_hashugar`?

Comment: @maicher - [253381, 1, 'first', 'king', 'CEO', 'Jewelry & Toys', '11111', '22222', nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]

Comment: In the above comment - Last 4 nils are of lead_details table. lead_details table has columns - id, account_id, stars, score. So because of the lead_details columns(id, account_id) are being overwritten. Any way to differentiate mysql2 query result based on the tables while doing joins??

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand it right, the columns from second table overwrites columns from first table.

I would propose not to select the unwanted columns.

You can achieved that by defining in SQL explicitly which columns from second table you want to load: "stars" and "score".

```
"SELECT leads.*, lead_details.stars, lead_details.score FROM leads LEFT JOIN lead_details ON lead_details.id=leads.id AND lead_details.account_id = leads.account_id WHERE leads.status=1 AND leads.account_id=1 AND leads.id > 253380"
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response @maicher . But the problem is the columns count is really huge, close to 43 in each table, so I am not supposed to do that way.